# Android disable an element of listview in Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-listview

I have a problem.

I implemented a navigation drawer with a listView, and I want disable a item of this listview. I want that the user see the item disable, because it take a different color, and you can't clicked it.
The problem, only the activity knows when it be disabled.

an obvious example of a button:

```
Button but =...
but.setEnables(false);
```

and now the button change the colour, and you can't click it.

I want do the same for an element of listView.
I tryed this:

```
nameListView.getChildAt(position).setEnabled(false);
```

but this don't work.

What can i do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using Adapter? Like this:

```
nameListView.getAdapter().getItem(position).setEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Thanks @muumuutech You helped me find the way

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

In the class who represent the item of navigation drawer, I add a boolean attribute (enable)

```
public class NavDrawerItem {

     ....
     private boolean enable;

     .....

     public boolean isEnable() {
          return enable;
     }

     public void setEnable(boolean enable) {
          this.enable = enable;
     }
 }
```

And in my adapter, override te method isEnable(position):

```
@Override
public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
    return getItem(position).isEnable();
};
```

Now, in my activity, when the navigation drawer is open, execute this method:

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    NavDrawerItem itemToDisable = (NavDrawerItem) mDrawerList.getAdapter().getItem(0);
    itemToDisable.setEnable(centroComercial!=null); //Condition to disable item

    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Before this method, system "redrawer" navigation drawer, and now the item isn't enable.
The only thing that does not change color, for more usability.